# Why can't I use my JSON data?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, json

I am trying to read some JSON data from an AJAX function. Here is the AJAX I am using:

```
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetCoords',
                data: "{}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var text = JSON.stringify(data);
                    $("#jsonData").html(text);
                    alert(text);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
```

I also have use JSON.parse in place of stringify, and objects return undefined or not at all. This comes from a C# function which looks like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static string GetCoords()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM DRAW ORDER BY DrawID DESC;", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(serializer.Serialize(rows));
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);                
            }
        }
    }
```

It is returning JSON data: Here is what it looks like on the Debugger Console and when I call the function in a paragraph tag:

```
[{"DrawID":925,"xCoord":466,"yCoord":201},{"DrawID":924,"xCoord":385,"yCoord":318},{"DrawID":923,"xCoord":768,"yCoord":159},{"DrawID":922,"xCoord":543,"yCoord":214},{"DrawID":921,"xCoord":329,"yCoord":172}]
```

However, when I send it to the paragraph tag in JQuery or call it in an HTML paragraph, here is what it looks like:

```
{"d":"[{\"DrawID\":925,\"xCoord\":466,\"yCoord\":201},{\"DrawID\":924,\"xCoord\":385,\"yCoord\":318},{\"DrawID\":923,\"xCoord\":768,\"yCoord\":159},{\"DrawID\":922,\"xCoord\":543,\"yCoord\":214},{\"DrawID\":921,\"xCoord\":329,\"yCoord\":172}]"}
```

I have two questions: 
(1) Why am I not able to use this data to insert the xCoords and yCoords into a canvas? I have tried many formats: (data.d[0].xCoord, d[0].xCoord, text.d[0].xCoord, text[0].xCoord, and so on).
(2) Is the second format above going to be a problem in trying to extract that data for painting on the canvas (it's the backslashes that I am wondering about)?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you returning string? Can be easier if you'll return rows.

Comment: It is possible that your Ajax call is returning before your document is ready. make sure that you call that ajax function inside ``$(document).ready(/*here8/);`` to ensure your ``#jsonData`` is available when you try to display it.

Comment: Can you give me an example @lujcon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your success function, you do not stringify or json.Parse the 'data' variable, but rather the data.d variable.  'd' is the member of the json return that you need to parse.

So, change, `var text = JSON.stringify(data);` to `var text = JSON.stringify(data.d);` and you should be golden.

Comment: This, along with the C# answer by @lujcon answer solved my problem. I've created a community wiki answer combining his and your answers. Thank you. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseJSON`, as such:

```
myThing = {"d":"[{\"DrawID\":925,\"xCoord\":466,\"yCoord\":201},{\"DrawID\":924,\"xCoord\":385,\"yCoord\":318},{\"DrawID\":923,\"xCoord\":768,\"yCoord\":159},{\"DrawID\":922,\"xCoord\":543,\"yCoord\":214},{\"DrawID\":921,\"xCoord\":329,\"yCoord\":172}]"};

myJSON = $.parseJSON(myThing.d);
alert (myJSON[0].DrawID); //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static Dictionary<string, object>[] GetCoords()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM DRAW ORDER BY DrawID DESC;", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(serializer.Serialize(rows));
            return rows.ToArray();                
        }
    }
}
```

Java script:

```
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: 'Default.aspx/GetCoords',
            data: "{}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    var x = value.xCoord;
                    /// do something with it ;)
                });
                var text = JSON.stringify(data);
                $("#jsonData").html(text);
                alert(text);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This has actually formatted the JSON correctly back to my Javascript, but I still can't do anything with the data -- I can't extract something like alert(text.d[0].xCoord);

Comment: ?? What data are you getting back??

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but it doesn't deserve it. It has actually helped make the JSON return so I can correctly turn it into a Javascript variable. I am almost there.

Comment: Problem solved thanks to this answer and @JustinRusso. I have made a community Wiki answer and upvoted yours.

Comment: I've just modified my answer - but looks that I'm wrong with the javascript part... MS serialization surprises me all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had to return rows in my C# code as @lujcon said:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetCoords()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM DRAW ORDER BY DrawID DESC;", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(serializer.Serialize(rows));
            return rows;                
        }
    }
}
```

Then I had to change my `var text = JSON.stringify(data);` to var text = `JSON.stringify(data.d);` as @JustinRusso said. Works now. Thanks, everyone.